# ERROR: Excel ran out of resources while attempting to calculate one or more formulas. As a result, these formulas cannot be evaluated

Tags: excel, out-of-memory

Running into the above error message on my excel workbook.  When I open the workbook I can input data and new formulas, but if I input a new date in sheet 1, I get the error at which point it keeps popping up whenever I do anything anywhere in the workbook.

The new date columns in sheet 1 do get pulled in many (more than I could count when I traced dependants) COUNTIF, SUMIF, XLOOKUP, etc. formulas but I need these and don't know any workarounds.

I feel it shouldn't be these anyway, as the workbook is not particularly big at only 380kb.

Very frustrating and having checked many of the suggested solutions on google I am having no luck.

Running:

Microsoft® Excel® for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2210 Build 16.0.15726.20070) 64-bit

Device name:    REDACTED-OMEN,
Processor:  Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-9750H CPU @ 2.60GHz   2.59 GHz,
Installed RAM:  16.0 GB (15.9 GB usable),
Device ID:  REDACTED,
Product ID: REDACTED,
System type:    64-bit operating system, x64-based processor,
Pen and touch:  No pen or touch input is available for this display,

Tried limiting number of processors the workbook uses to just 1 processor.  Hoping to reduce hyperthreading.

Removed all formula errors that could be found by the excel formula error checker.

Removed some (but not all) COUNTIF, SUMIF, XLOOKUP, etc. formulas to try and determine if this was causing the resource issue.  Did not solve problem.

Comment: Are you restricting the ranges passed to your formulas? Using larger than necessary ranges (and certainly entire column references) within array-processing formulas is not at all a good idea.

Comment: @JosWoolley I had some full column references, but none were array formulas.  That being said, I have removed them and restricted all the ranges.  Still getting the error, so now I am just copying all the info across into a new spreadsheet and hoping that will fix the issue.